# Eggless milk 'mayonnaise' - how do milk and oil emulsify without lecithin? What's the science behind it?

Tags: food-science, emulsion, mayonnaise

The recipe:

Ingedients:

100 ml milk
200 ml oil
Lemon juice
Salt

Instructions:

1. Whiz 100 ml milk up - 30 secs
2. Slowly add 200 ml oil
3. Move the blender up and down to help emulsify
4. Flavour with salt and lemon juice
5. Whiz up until thick

"Note: It's NOT 100% fool proof – if blender is hot the mayo splits."

Here's the video: https://youtube.com/watch?v=iEOecpzD01c

This is not the first time I see this kind of recipe, how do oil and milk emulsify? Why the note says that when the mixture gets hot it starts to separate and what's the purpose of the first step "whiz the milk up before adding the oil"?

Comment: Why post the exact same question again after the first was closed as 'needing detail'? Add the detail, then it will go to the review queue for potential reopening. This will just be closed again, presumably for the same reason. https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/123478/eggless-milk-mayonnaise-how-do-milk-and-oil-emulsify-without-lecithin-what?noredirect=1 [can only be seen by high rep users]

Comment: Yeah and what kind of "detail" can I add given that this is all the information I have?

Comment: The ingredients & method used in the video, at least. The video could be used as an external reference, but you shouldn't make people go off-site to know what your question is - most especially when there's a 3-minute video to have to watch, explaining something that could be read in 15 seconds. Plus, of course, if the video is ever taken down, there's no question left.

Comment: OK. I added the 'method' although I don't see how it relates to the question posted above.

Comment: @TheLostInUnknown it is very rare in cooking/recipes that a method doesn't matter. Especially in a case where you are asking about the "science" behind it (I suppose the physics of the emulsion getting created), this absolutely depends on the method.

Answer (score 1):

[Milk proteins (mainly casein) are emulsifiers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6836175/), because [milk itself is an emulsion](https://www.aocs.org/stay-informed/inform-magazine/featured-articles/emulsions-making-oil-and-water-mix-april-2014?SSO=True):

> Milk is an example of an o/w [oil/water] emulsion, in which the fat phase or cream forms tiny droplets within the skim milk, or water phase.

As such, emulsifying vegetable oil in milk is pretty much just a matter of getting the emulsifying milk proteins to link to even more fat molecules, which they can do to a lesser extent than the extremely powerful emulsifiers in egg yolks.  This is why it's both possible to create a "milk mayonnaise", and why that mixture breaks much more easily.

If you want to know a lot more about it scientifically, read the papers from the two links at the beginning of this answer.

As for why you blend the milk before adding the oil: that's both to make sure that the milk proteins are well-distributed, and to agitate the milk so that the stream of oil disperses quickly.  Also, casein denatures when it gets hot, which is why the emulsion would break.

Alternately, you can also [create an oil/milk emulsion using synthetic membranes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0011916409003816).

Comment: So, it's like fixing a broken mayonnaise? You're basically adding the oil to an emulsion?

Comment: Sorry, not quite following your question.